# Removing from temporary DataTable if ID meets DataSet.DataTable value

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatable

I'm working on an algorithm to loop through an existing DataSet.DataTable and Temporary - DataTable.

I have put a loop in a loop to find the value of the ID in each row. My hope is to then remove the Row from the Temporary DataTable if they match. (to later put into a datagrid)

I get an error when it find a match and tries to delete it;

"Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute."

I think this is throwing a wobbly because I'm trying to remove from a DataTable that's currently being used, but I can't think of a solution to fix my issue.

Could anyone more experienced lend a hand?

```
int res_index = 0;

foreach (DataRow r in myDataSet.tbl_reservation)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("r" + myDataSet.tbl_reservation.Rows[res_index]["tableID"].ToString());

    int rID = (int)myDataSet.tbl_reservation.Rows[res_index]["tableID"];

    int tmp_index = 0;

    foreach (DataRow t in tmp_table.Rows)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("t" + tmp_table.Rows[tmp_index]["tableID"].ToString());

        int tID = (int)tmp_table.Rows[tmp_index]["tableID"];

        if (rID == tID)
        {
            tmp_table.Rows.RemoveAt(tmp_index);
        }

        tmp_index++;
    }

    res_index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I have understood correctly, but to remove elements from the temp table you could apply the `Select` method, then call `Delete` for the found rows and finally call `AcceptChanges` to effectively remove the rows

```
   foreach (DataRow r in myDataSet.tbl_reservation.Rows)
   {
        int rID = (int)r["tableID"];

        // Find all the rows with the desidered tableID in temp_table
        DataRow[] toRemove = tmp_table.Select("tableID=" + rID.ToString());
        foreach(DataRow r in toRemove)
            r.Delete();  // Delete doesn't try to remove the row, just marks it as deleted
   }
   // All the rows marked as deleted are effectively removed from the table rows collection
   tmp_table.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this;

```
var diff= table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable(),
                                                DataRowComparer.Default).ToDateTable();
```

Basically it gives you everything in the first table that isn't in second table. If the `DataRowComparer.Default` does not match how you want then you need to define and equality comparer and pass it to except instead (for example you could make one that just compares 1 column value where I think defualt will compare all values in each row).

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a collection in the middle of an a foreach loop

You have to use a for loop or store the index into temporary storage and delete later

```
foreach (DataRow r in myDataSet.tbl_reservation)
{
//MessageBox.Show("r" + myDataSet.tbl_reservation.Rows[res_index["tableID"].ToString());

int rID = (int)myDataSet.tbl_reservation.Rows[res_index]["tableID"];

int tmp_index = 0;

for(int tmp_index = 0;tmp_index<tmp_table.Rows.Count;tmp_index++)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("t" + tmp_table.Rows[tmp_index]["tableID"].ToString());

    int tID = (int)tmp_table.Rows[tmp_index]["tableID"];

    if (rID == tID)
    {
        tmp_table.Rows.RemoveAt(tmp_index);
        tmp_index--;
    }

}
```